# Как найти и вывести элемент из ArrayList C#?

Tags: c#, динамические-массивы

имеется сдедующая программа: Пользователь вводит информацию, эта информация заносится в ArrayList. Необходимо чтобы при нажатии на клавишу F3 выводился тот элемент, который пользователь введёт с клавиатуры. Почему у меня выводится объект когда я обращаюся по индексу. Помогите пожалуйста как вывести сам элемент.

```
namespace double_linked_list
{
    struct Info
    {
        public string stage;
        public string count_employees;
        public string status;
        public int year;
        public int day;
        public int mounth;
        public int expenses;

        public void GetInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Этап: {stage}\nКоличество сотрудников на данном этапе: {count_employees}\nСрок выполнения работы: {year}/{mounth}/{day}\nСтатус: {status}\nМатериальные затраты:{expenses} руб.\n");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            Info myInfo = new Info();

            ConsoleKeyInfo key;

            Console.Write("Введите количество записей: ");

            int elementsCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int n;

            for (n = 0; n < elementsCount; n++)
            {
                Console.Write("Введите этап(1 - 2): ");
                myInfo.stage = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Введите статус(Готов/Неготов): ");
                myInfo.status = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Введите кол-во сотрудников: ");
                myInfo.count_employees = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Срок выполнения работы(год): ");
                myInfo.year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Срок выполнения работы(месяц): ");
                myInfo.mounth = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Срок выполнения работы(день):");
                myInfo.day = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Материальные затраты:");
                myInfo.expenses = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                list.Add(myInfo);
                Console.Clear();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Вывод Записей:\n");

            foreach (Info inf in list)
            {
               inf.GetInfo();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Нажмите клавишу F2 для добавления элемента");
            Console.WriteLine("Нажмите клавишу F3 для поиска элемента");
            Console.WriteLine("Нажмите клавишу Escape для выхода из программы");

            do
            {
                key = Console.ReadKey();
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.F2)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.Write("Введите этап(1 - 2): ");
                        myInfo.stage = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Введите статус(Готов/Неготов): ");
                        myInfo.status = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Введите кол-во сотрудников: ");
                        myInfo.count_employees = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Срок выполнения работы(год): ");
                        myInfo.year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Срок выполнения работы(месяц): ");
                        myInfo.mounth = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Срок выполнения работы(день): ");
                        myInfo.day = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Материальные затраты: ");
                        myInfo.expenses = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        list.Add(myInfo);

                        Console.Write("Нажмите ввод, чтобы добавить новый элемент(Клавиша N - не добавлять элемент): ");

                        key = Console.ReadKey();

                        Console.Clear();

                        Console.WriteLine("Вывод Записей:\n");

                        foreach (Info inf in list)
                        {
                            inf.GetInfo();
                        }

                    } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.N);
                }
                else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.F3)
                {
                    Console.Write("Введите номер элемента: ");
                    int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    foreach (Info inf in list)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(list[num]);
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Нажмите клавишу F2 для добавления элемента");
                Console.WriteLine("Нажмите клавишу F3 для поиска элемента");
                Console.WriteLine("Нажмите клавишу Escape для выхода из программы");
            } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: не надо пользоваться `ArrayList` - вместо него нужно использовать `List<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо перебирать не элементы листа, а выводить элементы объекта, хранящегося под номером в листе:

```js
else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.F3)
                {
                    Console.Write("Введите номер элемента: ");
                    int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Info inNum = list[num];
                    Console.Write(inNum.stage);
                    Console.Write(inNum.status);
                    Console.Write(inNum.count_employees);
                    Console.Write(inNum.year);
                    Console.Write(inNum.mounth);
                    Console.Write(inNum.day);
                    Console.Write(inNum.expenses);
                 }
```